# Integration, is this correct?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

i need to find 
$$\int_{\Gamma}z^i\,dz$$
along the upper semi-circle of radius $1$ and $-\pi<Arg(z)<\pi$.

I paramatrized $\Gamma$ as $e^{i\theta}, 0\leq\theta\leq\pi$:
$$\int_0^{\pi}ie^{i\theta}\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^id\theta=\int_0^{\pi}ie^{i\theta}e^{-\theta}d\theta=i\int_0^{\pi}e^{(i-1)\theta}d\theta=\frac{1-i}{2}e^{(1-i)\theta}\Big|_0^{\pi}=\frac{1-i}{2}(-e^{-\pi}-1)$$
Is this ok? Because my book dos this
$$z^i=e^{iLog(z)}$$
and plugs para. for $\Gamma$ into $e^{iLog(z)}$. But answers are the same, why does the book do this long way?

Comment: Why? Because the author thought about this from a different angle than you. The $2$ ways are exactly identical

Comment: It’s past my bedtime, so I could be wrong, but I’m pretty sure that $-\pi < \arg(z) < \pi$ defines a **circle** (excluding the number $-1$) and **not a semicircle**.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor you are right, but OP is right as well, look again and look till the end

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor That's the principal argument of $z$ useful for determining branch cuts. It has nothing to do with $\Gamma$. In this case the contour is a semicircle. Also $Arg(z)\subseteq \arg(z)$ and are not necessarily the same. $\arg(z)=Arg(z)+2n\pi,\,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex numbers $a$ and $b$ the power $a^{b}$ has to be defined carefully. Here, the author is defining it as $e^{b Log (a)}$ where Log is the principal branch of logarithm. Your claim that $(e^{i\theta})^{i} =e^{-\theta}$ requies a proof and the proof is by going to the definition. In other words the author is making your computation rigorous.